# Boot linux kernel 5.8.6-1 with manjaro x64 gets stuck at bios screen

Tags: linux, windows, boot, updates, kernel

I dual boot windows and manjaro. Last night I suddenly could not log in to manjaro kernel 5.8.6-1 anymore (the boot got stuck at the MSI-logo) but had to go to advanced options and choose 5.7.19-2 and that worked. Windows was acting weird too. Some programs froze while others worked fine. I can't think of anything that could have caused this except maybe a windows update, or that I tried to click on my windows files (in the manjaro explorer). How do I fix this?

Comment: Hey, I got the same issue. Could you solve it?

Comment: Any workout? same issue